# How to change .htaccess file to work right in localhost?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

I have this snippet code in my `.htaccess` file to prevent users from hotlinking the server's images:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?itransformer.es/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|wbmp)$ http://itransformer.es [R,L]
```

Of course, it is not working in my localhost, but don't know how to achieve it.
My guess is that I should change the domain name with any wildcard.
Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you try your guess out and see what happens ?

Comment: I'd do it, but how?

Comment: @ManoloSalsas Begin by [reading the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (also [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), and [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)). [SF] is a place for getting help doing your work, not for us to do the work for you.

Comment: @Iain - Sorry for that. I think now it could help someone.

Comment: @voretaq7 - Thanks for the reference. Now I'm ready to begin understanding the syntax. I was really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://%{HTTP_HOST}/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|wbmp)$ %{HTTP_HOST} [R=404,L]
```

Comment: This question seems to be blocking my account. I've edited my question a few times but nothing changes. Could you please vote me up so I can ask more questions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not just this question, but also your other two with negative scores. You could contribute some positive Answers to other people's questions, once you get an upvote or two the ban will be automatically lifted.

Comment: All right, but I don't see any other question with negative score...

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/545821/unknown-processes-of-apache2 and http://serverfault.com/questions/532267/my-server-has-falled-over

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I thought they were definitively removed.